# Xcode debugger shows values for only some variables. How to correct this behavior?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, xcode-debugger

The debugger shows values of some variables correctly. However, for other variables, no value is shown.

[image]

As shown in the image, the debugger shows value for displayNameHairFront, whereas the value for displayNameHairBack is missing.

I have already ensured that I am running the debug build variant. Also, the optimisations have been set to None.

Comment: Maybe you are not in the scope yet or the variable is optimized out. Also a reference variable need not have a location in memory.

Comment: I am clearly in scope (as can be seen from the image). I have crossed the setting of variable (displayNameHairBack) but it's value is still not shown. Moreover, I have set optimizations to None (also mentioned in the question). Thirdly, 'displayNameHairBack' is not a reference variable.